# in Makefile remove folders if a filename with the same basename exist

Tags: bash, makefile

I need to remove in the following case

```
.
├── a
│   └── index.html
├── a.rst
├── b
│   └── index.html
├── c
│   └── index.html
└── c.rst
```

folder `a` and `c` not `b`.

I make it work with this Makefile:

```
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: clean                                                                                       
                                                                                                    
HTML_TARGETS:= $(patsubst %.rst,%.html,$(wildcard *.rst))                                           
                                                                                                    
clean: $(HTML_TARGETS)                                                                              
                                                                                                    
%.html: %.rst                                                                                       
    @echo rm $(basename $@ .html) 
$

$ make
rm a
rm c
$
```

Is there a better way to write it ? (the patsubst use an unneeded `.html` sub)

Comment: `$(basename $@ .html)` doesn't mean what you think: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html  It's **super** weird and not right to have a target with a name `foo.html` delete `foo`.  If you ever want this makefile to do more stuff than just delete you will run into problems.  Why don't you just have the recipe for the `clean` target delete the files that you want?  And of course you have to use `rm -r` if you want to delete a directory.

Comment: ">  Why don't you just have the recipe for the clean target delete the files that you want?"
Because this Makefile will live in a folder I don't know what files will live in
"> you have to use rm -r"
Yes sure @echo is here only to check that I catch a, c and not b

Comment: I don't mean you should hardcode the values.  You an still generate them based on wildcards etc.  I just don't understand why you want to create separate pattern rules to do it instead of putting it all in the recipe for `clean`.  As I said, make treats a rule as a target to be brought up to date and subverting that to mean "a target representing some other file that should be removed" will very likely lead to confusing behavior, if your makefile needs to do other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I mean is why don't you just do something like:

```
.PHONY: clean

HTML_DIRS := $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(wildcard */*.html)))
RST_FILES := $(basename $(wildcard *.rst))

clean:
        echo rm -r $(filter $(RST_FILES),$(HTML_DIRS))
```